# How to make embedded Twitter feed responsive in size for smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter, feed

Here is the code generated by Twitter to embed into my web site:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="250" data-height="1000" href="https://twitter.com/Supernova_Style?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Supernova_Style</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I have tried a few different ways in CSS to change the width of the feed but it doesn't work.  I would like to keep the twitter feed visible as the screen size is shrunk to mobile size.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: so you want it to be a certain size but have it shrink to fit if its too big?

Answer (score 5):

We've found lately that Twitter's fairly new code generator for embedded profile timelines at [publish.twitter.com](https://publish.twitter.com/) still creates the issue of the timeline overflowing the container width for iOS devices, particularly with width and height settings (and no data-tweet-limit set).

Currently we're handling this issue via added css (with selector potentially preceeded by your additional specificity, as needed):

`.twitter-timeline {
    width: 100vw !important;
}`

Comment: This value worked for me too, thanks. I had my twitter feed in an iframe though so instead of CSS, I used data-width="100vw" on the twitter timeline link.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a container and set the attributes to `width: 100%; height:auto;` then size your container appropriately. You can then use media queries where necessary.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/o6qrxyga/1/

Comment: Be careful that `height: auto` may override the intrinsic height of the iframe, truncating the content. Perhaps leave that part out in some cases.

Comment: That's a really good point, @MichaelBenjamin, I'll make an edit.